# Invalid viewstate on certain .net pages

Tags: .net, viewstate

We are getting an Invalid viewstate exception in our .net 2 application. This seems to only happen on 2 particular pages. Page A can have a really big viewstate (around 5MB! I know, it's legacy code), while Page B's viewstate is normal (10k). A user will normally navigate to Page B after using Page A. The thing that we find strange is that we have 3 users who regularly use these pages but we only get the errors from 2 of those users. They all use IE8.

The pages do not use AJAX and we are not using a web farm.

Is the error just down to the ridiculously large viewstate of Page A? If so, why does it happen on Page B too? And why is it caused by 2 particular users?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you paste the exception you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Compressing the 5MB viewstate (as a quickfix) should make it faster and possibly more robust. 
See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/ViewStateCompression.aspx

If the problem is related to sending so much data it may help. (Once the data is on the server it should be ok)

Comment: Thanks Tedd, I'll give that a go. Hopefully it will sort out the errors on Page B too. Any idea as to why it only happens to certain users?